# Is there a way to write a line of code to display a name automatically without giving parameters in codeigniter

Tags: php, html

I want to write a code in home.php file that can display my name automatically when I run it on the browser without having to include any parameters on the code or the browser

I tried this

```
public function show(string $name)
{
         echo "<h1>Welcome to Sai Pali</h1> - $name";
}
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given function?

Comment: If you're logged into the PHP application then it should be able to retrieve your name from the Session details or your user details in the application's database. Or if you are, for example, on a Windows domain you can use Windows/Kerberos authentication to retrieve the current user's details from Active Directory. Aside from these and similar options, I'm not sure how you think the webserver is going to magically guess what your name is :-)